# E-Mail Alert when no new files/directories created for past hour or a day

Tags: linux, alert

I would like to get an alert whenever there is no new file or directory created over a particular time i.e. for last one hour or a day

The server gets log files from various sources and is saved in below fromat:

**/u01/log/server_name/2021-04/03/file.log**

**/u01/log/server_name/YYYY-MN/DD/file.log**

Thanks for your help in advance

Javeed

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple shell-script that will check if the file from today exists. If you'd like to check for yesterday's file, you can adjust the `date` command to be `date -d "yesterday" "+%H %M %d %m %Y"`. Hopefully this gives you enough to adjust to meet your requirements.

```
# get the current hour, minute, day, month and year into variables we can use
read HOUR MINUTE DAY MONTH YEAR < <(date "+%H %M %d %m %Y")
# build the file path you're looking for
FILE="/u01/log/server_name/${YEAR}-${MONTH}/${DAY}/file.log"
# Check if the file exists, send an email if it doesn't
if [ ! -f "$FILE" ] ; then
  echo "$FILE does not exist" | mail support@myemail.com
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Sript 1 is listing the directories declared in script. Taking it little further in script 2 list directories like /u01/log/2021-02. Need Help in script 2 it is failing.

## Script 1

#!/bin/bash

arr=(/u01/log/*)

for ((i=0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i++)); do

ls -ld  "${arr[$i]}"

done

Success: output -->

/u01/log/log-server1

....

.....

so on..

## script 2

#set -xv

#!/bin/bash

MON=date '+%m'

DAY=date '+%d'

YEAR=date '+%Y'

YEAR-MON=date '+%Y-%m'

arr=(/u01/log/*)

for ((i=0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i++)); do

FILE="${arr[$i]}/`${YEAR-MON}`"

ls -ld $FILE

done

Error:
list.sh: line 4: +%m: command not found

list.sh: line 5: +%d: command not found

list.sh: line 6: +%Y: command not found

list.sh: line 7: YEAR-MON=date: command not found

list.sh: line 13: MON: command not found

Once this is resolved it should email alert if no new files created in /u01/log/YEAR-MON

Thanks
Javeed